# What is the correct method to alter the source field value in Contributions?

Tags: contributions

I want to alter the contribution source field so that I can add custom data in the pattern shown below
[Payment Type] - Online Payment - [Contribution Page title]

I am planning to use `hook_civicrm_pre` where `$op == Contribution` and alter the value based on the Contribution Object Data available ?
Is that the correct method ?